# Как определить ip пользователя если на сайте установлен анти бот фильтр Cloudflare

Tags: php, ip

Я использую анти бот фильтр от cloudflare и мне нужно определять ip адрес пользователя. Я пытался использовать функцию $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; и получался ip адрес в Сан-Франциско, при этом я нахожусь в спб и не использую прокси

Comment: X-forwarded-for

Comment: Вот так делает CodeIgniter: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/ea1e3c8b5425fb68e33f1d5f72c5888295537076/system/core/Input.php#L418

Comment: Вообще `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']`, но это небезопасно ))

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare возвращает вам реальный IP пользователя. Нужно лишь настроить Nginx, дабы его можно было получить.

Вот офф.дока:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/restoring-visitor-ips/restoring-original-visitor-ips/

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "IP: ";
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
```